# How to use iTunes like scrollbars

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, nsscroller

what is the best way to display iTunes like scrollers in Leopard? Is there a 'system call' to change the look and feel of scrollers in cocoa or carbon?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell, these are private UI widgets. If you really need the iTunes look, you can roll your own, either by making your own images, or using the tools provided by Cocoa to generate the appropriate images. This guy has made an example of how to do this [here](http://espresso-served-here.com/2008/06/18/creating-itunes-scrollers/)

Comment: yes I found him before posting the question. Thank you though.

Comment: It's been a while, but from what I remember, he did it by building the images at runtime, I think maybe with Core Image. Googling the link, I think there was example code that was picked up by spiders, so you might try that.